# Reuse API Proxy Policies within same Organization

Tags: apigee

How do I use a common policies across multiple API proxies.
What should be the approach, TIA.

Comment: I can understand the interest in the topic, but this question is very broad.  Apigee just gave a 1-hr webinar on this very topic-- there's a lot of ground to cover.  What is most important to you: code maintainability, latency, flow flexibility, deploy-less updates, ability to debug?  The approach (or "best" approach, as you probably implied) depends on what you define as most important.  Without defined criteria, this question may produce answers that don't fit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Inside any Apigee Edge application bundle (the artifact containing the xml definition of proxies, policies and targets) you can package any number of proxy and target definitions. These proxies can have completely independent base paths. That is, they do not need to be functionally related. Now, if you have a number of reusable policies across these proxies, all of these policies can be referenced by multiple proxies or the targets, as long as they are present in the same bundle. However, my suggestion is that not to put unrelated proxies in the same application bundle unless there is a significant amount of common functionalities across these proxies. Because the re-use may be short-lived as soon as something changes for proxy 1 but not for proxy 2. Also larger application bundles with more number of proxies in them may be difficult to maintain from coding point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of policy, you may find using organization or environment level resources a useful solution: http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/content/resource-files